# Objective-C How to POST form-data using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a webservice and I can successfully make post calls to it via Postman utility. On Postman the settings are[image: Postman settings]

I am unable to make the same call using Afnetworking using code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"body": @{@"email":@"email@gmail.com",@"name":@"myName"}};
[manager POST:@"http://myURL.com/user" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

My guess is that I am not setting the form-data correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to serialize your params dictionary and then string encode it, since your body parameter has a JSON object in it. 
Try using this :

```
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": @"email@gmail.com", @"name": @"myName"};
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"body":json};
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:@"http://myURL.com/user" parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", myString);
    }];
```

Comment: Serialization and string encoding was something that I was missing. Thanks